# mongoose population (refs) is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created two models where I am trying to ref one model to another but it's not working and I don't have any idea about it I used it exactly the same way as in the mongoose example but it is not helping, the only difference between my working and their example is I have two different files for both models and I am exporting them to use in another file

The example I took reference from [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#checking-populated)

**First Model**

```
const userModel = require('./userModel')
const {Schema} = mongoose

const tweet = new Schema({
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    },
    msg:{
        type: String,
        maxlength:140,
        required:true
    },
    tweetid:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    }
})

const tweetSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'userModel'
    },
    tweets: {
        type: [{tweet}],
        default: []
    }
})

const tweetModel = mongoose.model('tweet',tweetSchema)

module.exports = tweetModel
```

**Second Model**

```
const {Schema} = mongoose

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim:true
    },
    password: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true
    },
    follows: {
        type: [String],
        default: []
    }
})

const userModel = mongoose.model("User",userSchema) 

module.exports = userModel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reference string should be equal to the model name that you have passed to `mongoose.model`:

```js
const tweetSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    tweets: {
        type: [{tweet}],
        default: []
    }
})
```

Comment: I think by schema name you mean model name
`const userModel = mongoose.model("User",userSchema) `
So should i use the **userModel** in ref or **User**

Comment: I am still not able to get the result, it's still the same

Comment: what is your query to get the result?

Comment: I am using Robo 3t to see the results so i am not using any query

Comment: so how do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: Okay, I got the problem i was making a typo because of which it was not working, Thank you